# how to write complex if condition with File array in the lamba expression of stream API Android Java

Tags: java, android, if-statement, lambda

I have the following code

```
private ArrayList<String> findPhotos(Date startTimestamp, Date endTimestamp, String keywords, String longitude, String latitude) {
     
     ArrayList<String> photos = new ArrayList<String>();
     File[] fList = file.listFiles();
        if (fList != null) {
            for (File f : fList) {
                if (((startTimestamp == null && endTimestamp == null) || (f.lastModified() >= startTimestamp.getTime()
                        && f.lastModified() <= endTimestamp.getTime())
                ) && (keywords == "" || f.getPath().contains(keywords))
                        && (longitude == "" || f.getPath().contains(longitude))
                        && (latitude == "" || f.getPath().contains(latitude)))
                    photos.add(f.getPath());
            }
        }
    return photos
}
```

This function take five parameters:

1. Startime time
2. endtime
3. keywork
4. longitude
5. latitude

I filter them out to get the only desired results. I want to transfer this file array into lambda array and then perform following code.

```
Filter(startTimestamp == null && endTimestamp == null)
```

or

```
Filter(f -> f.lastModified() >= startTimestamp.getTime())
```

and

```
Filter(f -> f.getPath().contains(keywords) or (keywords == ""))
```

and

```
Filter(keywords == "" || f -> f.getPath().contains(keywords))
```

and

```
Filter(latitude== "" || f -> f.getPath().contains(latitude))
Filter(keywords == "" || f -> f.getPath().contains(keywords))
```

and then get only paths, then

```
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Once I filter them out the File array and then add only file paths into `Arraylist<String>`. Can anyone help me to turn this one into lambda expression?

Comment: What are you hoping to gain by using a lambda expression?

Comment: Enclose your code in `() -> {` and `}`.

Comment: If you are trying to turn that into a lambda expression, you are missing the point of lambda expressions.  Factor out and declare the logic as a (named) method and use a method reference.  Lambdas should be used for simple logic that can be expressed in "one or two" lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the following should achieve your desired result.

```
private List<String> findPhotos(Date startTimestamp,
                                Date endTimestamp,
                                String keywords,
                                String longitude,
                                String latitude) {
    return java.util.Arrays.stream(new file.listFiles())
                           .filter(f -> startTimestamp == null || f.lastModified() >= startTimestamp.getTime())
                           .filter(f -> endTimestamp == null || f.lastModified() <= endTimestamp.getTime())
                           .map(file -> file.getPath())
                           .filter(path -> keywords.isEmpty() || path.contains(keywords))
                           .filter(path -> longitude.isEmpty() || path.contains(longitude))
                           .filter(path -> latitude.isEmpty() || path.contains(latitude))
                           .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

- Method `stream`, in class `java.util.Arrays`, converts an array into a stream. In the above code, that stream will contain instances of class `java.io.File`.
- Method `map`, in interface `java.util.stream.Stream`, returns a new stream that, in the above code, contains `String` elements.
- Finally, all the paths that pass all the filters are collected into a `java.util.List`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your given approach:

- As others have already mentioned, the point of a lambda
  expression is that it should be short and easy to understand.
- To get the logical *and* of your multiple logical
  expressions you should chain the `filter(f -> ...)` calls.
  This is better than putting all the logic into one giant
  lambda expression.
- You need to understand the difference between `==` and
  `equals`. So instead of `keywords == ""` you probably
  want `keywords.equals("")`.
- You cannot use `ArrayList<String>` because
  `.collect(Colllectors.toList())` is declared to give
  a `List<String>`.

Considering all this you might end up with something like this

```
private List<String> findPhotos(Date startTimestamp, Date endTimestamp, String keywords, String longitude, String latitude) {
{
    File[] fList = file.listFiles();
    if (fList == null)
        return new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> photos = Arrays.stream(fList)
        .filter(f -> f.lastModified() >= startTimestamp.getTime())
        .filter(f -> f.getPath().contains(keywords))
        .filter(f -> keywords.equals("") || f.getPath().contains(keywords))
        .filter(f -> latitude.equals("") || f.getPath().contains(latitude))
        .filter(f -> keywords.equals("") || f.getPath().contains(keywords))
        .map(f -> f.getPath())  // convert File to String
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return photos;
}
```